# Galaxy Note N7000B com.android.gsf.login fails

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-note, google-apps

I am having Galaxy Note N7000B . I am having Samsung ICS 4.0.4 DCLR8 (Thai version) installed on my device.

Phone shows

> Unfortunately com.android.gsf.login has stopped

and phone hangs. Sometimes, after a start it hangs without any message but, keeps restarting all the services like network connections, background processes etc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `gsf = google services framework`. Do you have any google account connected at the device? it may be related with android market / google contact updates / or other google services

Comment: @madlymad yes .. know what GSF is.. what i dont knw is, why it has started failing suddenly? I'm using the device for a year now